# 6 wire transformer

Tags: power-supply, transformer, wire, output, coil

I have a transformer that is rather unusual. My issue is I have no Idea what wire does what. It is a 6 wire transformer. On one side we have one white and one back. On the other side we have one white, one, black, two red. Its rather strange as I said. I search online and I am seeing something close to the term "Double Primary Winding" what ever that means. I am trying to see how far I can step up 9v too. Just an experiment.

Comment: Many transformers have multiple secondary windings so a 6 wire transformer is not unusual. Your transformer could also have a double primary winding so as to be usable for both 120 and 240 volt applications.  Since color coding of wires on transformers is far from standardized, you will need either a  schematic or have to make voltage and continuity measurements to determine its functions.

Comment: The Transformer is from a Battery Backup (12v DC to 120 AC)

Comment: The Label Prints as followed, 430-0168 CLASS 130(B) Z150M LEI-4 E154512 2/17

Comment: It is quite unlikely that you can identify the transformer from the label as it is probably a "house number" (private) for a custom OEM part.  The only reliable way of documenting the transformer is to reverse-engineer the circuit.  It is unclear what you mean by "how far I can step up 9V" means in a "Battery Backup (12v DC to 120 AC)"???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is purely a guess, but I suspect that you've got a transformer which is intended to allow connection to either 120 or 240 VAC. The two black/white pairs are separate primaries, and the red is the secondary. Connection looks like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhByyi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>